# how H2 in intellij without installed H2

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, h2, h2-console

i'm army
army computer can install intellij, but can not install H2.
test need h2 or other database program.

i wish know h2 use with 'localhost:8080/h2-console'

thank you for read.

```
2023-01-05T23:47:23.106+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] anyway.sunwon.SunwonApplication          : Starting SunwonApplication using Java 19.0.1 with PID 6156 (C:\\Users\\CKIRUser\\Desktop\\sunwon\\out\\production\\classes started by CKIRUser in C:\\Users\\CKIRUser\\Desktop\\sunwon)
2023-01-05T23:47:23.111+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] anyway.sunwon.SunwonApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-01-05T23:47:23.187+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-01-05T23:47:23.187+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-01-05T23:47:25.137+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-01-05T23:47:25.225+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 75 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-01-05T23:47:26.289+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-01-05T23:47:26.306+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service \[Tomcat\]
2023-01-05T23:47:26.306+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: \[Apache Tomcat/10.1.4\]
2023-01-05T23:47:26.404+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.a.c.c.C.\[Tomcat\].\[localhost\].\[/\]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-01-05T23:47:26.406+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3217 ms
2023-01-05T23:47:26.509+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-01-05T23:47:27.118+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA
2023-01-05T23:47:27.120+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-01-05T23:47:27.129+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2023-01-05T23:47:27.392+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo \[name: default\]
2023-01-05T23:47:27.459+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.6.Final
2023-01-05T23:47:27.638+09:00  WARN 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting \[javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode\], use \[jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode\] instead
2023-01-05T23:47:27.895+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2023-01-05T23:47:28.487+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.h.m.i.EntityInstantiatorPojoStandard   : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: anyway.sunwon.domain.Book (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2023-01-05T23:47:28.746+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: \[org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform\]
2023-01-05T23:47:28.760+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-01-05T23:47:29.060+09:00  WARN 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] ocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer : Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: anyway.sunwon.repository.AdminUserRepository
2023-01-05T23:47:29.178+09:00  WARN 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-01-05T23:47:29.491+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with \[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@7eec5f21, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@79825521, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@440b0657, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@67a9dd22, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@619d188, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5d875af3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1fcb3a64, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@166bfb26, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3beb7681, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4632b036, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@76fd6789, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@21e50fa\]
2023-01-05T23:47:29.689+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-01-05T23:47:29.746+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-01-05T23:47:29.760+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] anyway.sunwon.SunwonApplication          : Started SunwonApplication in 7.529 seconds (process running for 8.562)
HikariProxyConnection@1662029991 wrapping conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA
jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
SA
2023-01-05T23:47:29.792+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-01-05T23:47:29.814+09:00 ERROR 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:761) \~\[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:748) \~\[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) \~\[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) \~\[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) \~\[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1\]
at anyway.sunwon.SunwonApplication.main(SunwonApplication.java:10) \~\[classes/:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) \~\[na:na\]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) \~\[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1\]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar \[INSERT INTO USER VALUES(1, 'testuser')\]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:101) \~\[spring-jdbc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3\]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) \~\[spring-jdbc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3\]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1538) \~\[spring-jdbc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3\]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:393) \~\[spring-jdbc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3\]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:431) \~\[spring-jdbc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3\]
at anyway.sunwon.H2Runner.run(H2Runner.java:37) \~\[classes/:na\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:758) \~\[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1\]
... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO \[\*\]USER VALUES(1, 'testuser')"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO USER VALUES(1, 'testuser') \[42001-214\]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:261) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifier(Parser.java:5656) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifierWithSchema(Parser.java:5616) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8328) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1632) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:814) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:237) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223) \~\[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214\]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) \~\[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na\]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) \~\[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na\]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:422) \~\[spring-jdbc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3\]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:381) \~\[spring-jdbc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3\]
... 11 common frames omitted

2023-01-05T23:47:29.853+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-01-05T23:47:30.061+09:00  WARN 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) \[90121-214\]
2023-01-05T23:47:30.062+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-01-05T23:47:30.066+09:00  INFO 6156 --- \[  restartedMain\] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly paste your Java program as well.

```
 stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) VALUES (1, 'Ramesh', 32, 'Ahmedabad', 2000.00 );");
```

Pasting the working SQL query in my current system, Thanks.